# Did Nala Maharaja had other special abilities besides cooking?

Tags: mahabharata

Nala Maharaja story appears in the Mahabharata. Nala Maharaja is known as [an expert in culinary art](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22770/5212) and a great manager of horses. He is also known as a great charioteer. Besides these, did he have any other special abilities? How did he get them?

Comment: Check this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nala

Comment: @CR241 Check [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22914/5212) answer. I know who is Nala. Linking wikipedia articles or blogs in the comments doesn't help to the site. Answers help.

Comment: Oh really. If you know who is Nala there is sense to post simple question here. Asking question and at same time  add an answer is it make sense to you?

Comment: @CR241 Totally makes sense if you know the help center. Read [Can I answer my own question?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and [Let's make our site an excellent repository of frequently asked significant questions about Hinduism!](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/802/5212).  Refrain from answering in comments and adding irrelevant links in the comments. Did you read the article before you posted? The wiki link you provided gives nothing about the abilities of Nala.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nala Maharaja was a ruler of the Nishadas. He had other special abilities besides cooking, managing horses and driving chariots very swiftly. He got them by the boons from Gods.

Nala was bestowed boons by the Gods who came to Damayanti swayamvara gave Nala boons when Nala was chosen by Damayanti.

Gods Indra, Agni, Yama and Varuna have attended Damayanti Swayamvara. Each god gave Nala Maharaja two boons.

- #### Indra

  1. His personal presence in the sacrifices performed by Nala.
  2. Blessed regions thereafter.
- #### Agni

  1. Agni's own presence whenver Nala desired and no danger from him.
  2. Also blessed with brighter regions thereafter.
- #### Yama

  1. Subtle taste in food.
  2. Excellence in Dharma.
- #### Varuna

  1. His own presence whenever he desired. It means whenever Nala desires, a stream of water would flow before Nala by his desire.
  2. Also gifted a celestial garland of flowers. By this boon, whenever Nala touches or crushes a flower, it would become more odourous and fresh than before.

From [this](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03057.htm) chapter of Vana Parva of Mahabharata,

> And after the daughter of Bhima had chosen Naishadha as her husband, the Lokapalas of exceeding effulgence with pleased hearts, **bestowed on Nala eight boons**. And Sakra, the lord of Sachi, bestowed on Nala the boon that he should be able to behold his godship in sacrifices and that he should attain to blessed legions thereafter, and Hutasana bestowed on him the boon of his own presence whenever Naishadha wished, and regions also bright as himself. And Yama granted him subtle taste in food as well as pre-eminence in virtue. And the lord of waters granted Nala his own presence whenever he desired, and also garlands of celestial fragrance. And thus each of them bestowed upon him a couple of boons.

Nala learnt Gambling from King Rituparna. In return, he taught Rituparna managing horses.

From Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam ninth skandha, chapter 9,

> Bhagīratha had a son named Śruta, whose son was Nābha. This son was different from the Nābha previously described. Nābha had a son named Sindhudvīpa, from Sindhudvīpa came Ayutāyu, and from Ayutāyu came Ṛtūparṇa, who became a friend of Nalarāja. **Ṛtūparṇa taught Nalarāja the art of gambling, and Nalarāja gave Ṛtūparṇa lessons in controlling and maintaining horses**. The son of Ṛtūparṇa was Sarvakāma. [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam Ninth Skandha  9.16-17](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/9/16-17)